# Is there a way to pass the host: value header in a URL for Apache virtual hosts?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, url, intranet

I have two virtual host websites on my Ubuntu 20.04 computer outside the regular Apache2 document root. I can access them just fine in my browser on the same computer.

I'm trying to also access these virtual host websites over the intranet from my phone, but can't.

I don't currently have a way to safely edit my phone's hosts file, which I think would be the real fix for this issue.

Is there a way to pass the host:value header within the URL in my phone browser?

I'm thinking something like: http://host:websiteA@192.168.0.10

Right now, all I can get on my phone browser is Apache's document root when I enter: http://192.168.0.10.

Here's how I have my virtual hosts set up on my computer in case my setup can be changed to also allow my phone to access these through my intranet.

```
000-default.conf file:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName websiteA
    DocumentRoot "/home/user/websiteA"
    <Directory /home/user/websiteA>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName websiteB
    DocumentRoot "/home/user/websiteB"
    <Directory /home/user/websiteB>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

hosts file:
127.0.0.1 websiteA
127.0.0.1 websiteB
```

If there is no method for including a header in a URL, then I suppose I can put an index page in my Apache document root that can make an ajax call with a host:websiteA header or host:websiteB header included to 192.168.0.10. I could have done that in the time it took to write this question, but it would be good to know if headers can be conveniently inserted in URLs somehow.

Thank you!

Comment: If you cannot afford to maintain a DNS server accessible by your phone, computer and the rest of your internal network, you can use alternative methods like *IP and/or (TCP) port based virtual hosts*. See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Thank you. I did try ports and that does work, but I'm trying to use virtual hosts with names rather than ports to mirror a production environment. My router does not allow custom DNS entries such as a built in hosts file would allow (I'm sure for coffee shop wifi security reasons). I could use a Raspberry Pi with Pi-Hole, but that's getting too elaborate. Port based virtual hosts would be far easier to deal with than setting that up for my needs. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: What I finally ended up doing was writing two scripts. One disables websiteA and enables websiteB. The other does the opposite. Both scripts restart Apache gracefully. I run each script with a custom keyboard shortcut. I finally realized I only work on one website at a time, so this is just very simple, works fine with my phone, and virtual host names work fine on the production server for both websites running at the same time with real DNS in play.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way yet to pass a header (host:value) in a url, but here are some alternative solutions for accessing apache virtual hosts on an apache server over an intranet from a phone browser that can only reach the server using an IP address:

1. Use port based virtual hosts. A phone browser can specify ports in the url:
   http://192.168.0.10:80, http://192.168.0.10:81, http://192.168.0.10:82 to access 3 different virtual hosts.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>...
<VirtualHost *:81>...
<VirtualHost *:82>...
```

In the ports.conf file:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82
```

2. Use IP based virtual hosts. If the intranet DHCP server will not allocate multiple IP addresses for the apache server, create alias IP addresses on the apache server:

Using Terminal, where ifconfig shows the apache computer to be enp8s0 192.168.0.110 execute these commands (I just picked the next 2 IP addresses, but first made sure they were not in use on the intranet):

```
sudo ifconfig enp8s0:0 192.168.0.111
sudo ifconfig enp8s0:1 192.168.0.112
```

Then define each virtual host by IP address in your virtual host configuation file(s). The first is the original default virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>...
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.111:80>...
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.112:80>...
```

These IP addresses are not persistent. They can be made persistent. A good article for creating additional IP addresses for a server temporarily and persistently is below. The article also discusses newer approaches than using ifconfig for network management:

https://www.2daygeek.com/add-additional-ip-secondary-ip-ubuntu-debian/

Be sure to set your /etc/hosts file with the new virtual host IP addresses so you can request them by name in your browser on your apache server:

```
192.168.0.111   websiteA
192.168.0.112   websiteB
```

3. Apparently there is a way to set up an index file to redirect a bare ip address request to the correct virtual host. I didn't explore this because both 1 and 2 solutions above already work for me, but it's an indirect way to get the host:value into a header. You can read about it in the apache documentation under "Using the ServerPath directive":

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html